# Xcode resources appear in product after removing from project

Tags: resources, xcode4

Using Xcode 4.0 sometimes when I remove resources from the project they still appear in the app when I run it, both in simulator and device.  I remove the resource from the Resources group by removing reference only, but afterwards also remove the actual file in Finder, and yet the resource magically appears in the app.

Doing a project clean did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bundle (and hence also an app) is just a directory, as seen from Unix and Unix-derived tools' point of view.

My guess is that they are still in the bundle because Xcode left a copy there once, and removing the originals in the source directory does not remove the copies in the built app bundle.

If you delete the app from the build directory (or the build directory altogether), you shouldn't see them any more inside a freshly built app.

Answer (score 3):

Xcode 4.0 has a lot of problems managing its projects' "derived data". Try opening the Organizer (Cmd-Shift-2) and clicking the Projects tab. Select your problem project in the source list, then find Delete button next to the Derived Data section near the top. Go ahead and confirm deleting the derived data, then build again (this will take longer as Xcode re-indexes your project).

Does that fix it?

Comment: Not sure if this works or not as I have deleted the app build directory and that works.  This is a good tip however.

Comment: This should be the same thing unless you've specified a separate build directory. Cleaning the target, however, *should* be removing the built product and so should deleting derived data.

Comment: It seems that this problem exist in xCode 5 as well.  I've performed action you suggested, and deleted App in device/simulator and it worked.